# Delete string in file based on entry input TCL

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I made a simple program accepting short user inputs and storing them in a file. With another button displaying each input in the file as a button. I am trying to create another proc that deletes the button and also the string in the file when i click on the button generated by the string. How do i do that? i tried `regsub` on the variable holding the values but it seems to delete them once and not every time.

**Code to grab current directory**

```
catch { set abspath [file readlink [info script]]} 
if { ![info exists abspath]} { set abspath $argv0 }
if { [regexp {^(\S+)\/\S+} $abspath matched dir]} { set BIN $dir }
file mkdir $BIN/debug
if {[file exists $BIN/debug/debug.txt]} { close [open $BIN/debug/debug.txt "w"]}
```

**GUI Code**

```
label .lbl -text "Enter something"
entry .en -justify center
button .sub -text "SUBMIT" -command "submit .en"
button .sho -text "SHOW" -command sho
button .cl -text "CLEAR" -command clear
grid .lbl -columnspan 3
grid .en -columnspan 3
grid .sub .sho .cl
```

**Submit Procedure**

```
proc submit {ent} {
global BIN
if {![file isdirectory $BIN/debug]} { file mkdir $BIN/debug }
set input [$ent get]
if {$input == "" || [string is space -strict $input]} {
$ent delete 0 end
.lbl configure -text "No empty strings"
} else {
set fp [open $BIN/debug/debug.txt a+]
$ent delete 0 end
puts $fp $input
close $fp
}
}
```

**Clear Procedure**

```
proc clear {} {
global BIN
if {[file exists $BIN/debug/debug.txt]} { close[open $BIN/debug/debug.txt "w"] } 
}
```

**Procedure to generate button for each item in file**

```
proc sho {} {
global BIN 
global filedat 
set w.gui
if {[info exists filedat]} { set filedat "" }
toplevel $w
wm title "values"
wm overrideredirect $w 1 
bind $w <Button-3> "destroy $w"
if {[file exists $BIN/debug/debug.txt]} {
set fp [open $BIN/debug/debug.txt r]
while {[gets $fp data] > -1} {
lappend filedat $data
}
close $fp
if {[info exist filedat]} {
set dcount 0
foreach item $filedat {
button $w.bn$dcount -text "$item" -font [list arial 10] -anchor w -fg white -bg black -command "del $item"
grid $w.bn$dcount -sticky w
incr dcount
}
} else {
label $w.nthLabel -text "Nothing in file" -bg black -fg white
grid $w.nthLabel
}
}
}
```

**Procedure to delete string (currently not working as expected)**

```
proc del {st} {
global filedat 
regsub -all $st $filedat "" filedat2
puts $filedat2
}
```

Comment: You can do the operation in line three a lot more efficiently and readably by using `set BIN [file dirname $abspath]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you delete the string with your *dep* proc you saved the new string in the variable *filedat2*.

The global variable *filedat* is never changed.

If you want to remove the string from your global variable, you have to pass this variable to regsub, instead of *filedat2*.

```
regsub -all $st $filedat "" filedat
```

Or if you prefer to save it in a temporal variable to perform some test you could use *filedat2* and then assign the variable again:

```
regsub -all $st $filedat "" filedat2
# ... the tests
if {[isOk]} {
    # update the variable
    set filedat $filedat2
} else {
    # leave the previous value
    puts "some error here"
}
```

Comment: To get a regular expression that matches an arbitrary literal in Tcl, [prefix it by `***=`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M82).

Comment: @DonalFellows thanks a lot, I didn't know this. Actually I always use reg exp with regexp and regsub.